# Why don't CPU fans have the buzzsaw effect (as in planes), even when their blades spin faster than 5k RPM?

Tags: estimation, aircraft, shock-waves, fan

I saw my CPU fan using HWinfo spinning faster than 5k RPM, in which the [buzzsaw effect](https://www.southampton.ac.uk/engineering/research/projects/buzz_saw_noise_and_non_linear_acoustics.page) starts in an [A3xx plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus#Commercial_aircraft).  Why doesn't my CPU fan do the buzzsaw effect, even though it's spinning faster than 5k RPM?

Comment: Tip speed is lower for small diameters than large ones at the same RPM?

Comment: @DKNguyen It is a 140mm PC fan.

Comment: And a plane's is several feet.

Comment: @DkNguyen, I have the one that runs about 11k RPM or higher.

Comment: And? The propeller, say a Cessna, is still many times larger while still running at 2700RPM which is still a large fraction of your 11krpm. You're too focused on RPM. Forget RPM. Calculate the tip speed. $v=\omega r$ 11krpm at 140mm is not even 1/4 the speed of sound. Airplane propellers run at tip speeds much closer to Mach 1.

Comment: @DKNguyen That should really be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: What is the buzz saw effect?

Comment: @Dale - When a propellor or turbofan blade exceeds the local speed of sound, it generates little shock waves that make the engine sound like a buzzsaw.

Comment: @honeste_vivere thanks, that is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The tip speed on an airplane propeller runs far closer to the speed of sound than your tiny fan where compressability starts to matter. Your tiny 140mm fan running at 11,000RPM has a much lower tip speed than a propeller a dozen times larger running at 1/4 the RPM.

Calculate the tip speed with $v=\omega r$. Your fan has a tip speed that isn't even Mach 0.25.

A Cessna has a 2.2m propeller running at 2700RPM has a tip speed of mach 0.9.